# Select All Columns Except Some in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to Select * except [x,y,z column names] in BigQuery? I see some solutions for MySQL but not sure if it applies to BQ.

Thank you.

Comment: the only answer I have is kind of extension of approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu which looks like not what works for you

Answer (score 151, accepted):

There is nothing in current BigQuery SQL dialect that will allow it. But since this is recurring request, we have added work item to support

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (a, b, c) FROM ...
```

**Update:** This functionality is now available in BigQuery standard SQL. Details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql
Example using public wikipedia table - select all columns except title and comment:

```
select * except(title, comment) from publicdata.samples.wikipedia limit 10
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks alot for implementing this! @MoshaPasumansky

Comment: It took a while, but it is available now. Answer updated.

Comment: Hi @MoshaPasumansky Thanks for adding this feature! But I just tried it in BQ and it didn't work. Could you let me know the exact syntax? Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example on public wikipedia table which skips title and comment columns: select * except(title, comment) from publicdata.samples.wikipedia limit 10

Comment: Hi @MoshaPasumansky. The example you gave did not work. And I was using: 
`SELECT
  * except(title,
    comment)
FROM
  bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia
LIMIT
  10`

Comment: did you uncheck Use Legacy SQL checkbox in the query options?

Comment: I did - I unchecked the legacy SQL box also - tried it with and without checking that box and neither worked.

Comment: Your query differs from mine - it has ":" as project separator instead of ".", and goes against project with dashes in it, which requires quoting with backticks. Did my exact query not work for you ?

Comment: can you give me job id for the failed query, I will look up the reason

Comment: Hi @MoshaPasumansky. You are right. It works if I used the exact query you had posted! And now I can use it for my own tables too. This is a very helpful feature. Thank you for helping to implement it!

Comment: Does except work with nested fields? (I seem to get syntax errors when I do except(Something.InnerThing) ) (likewise, with wildcards)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to [`SELECT * EXCEPT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#select-except) syntax there is a [`SELECT * REPLACE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#select-replace) syntax - both supported with Standard SQL introduced
Usage is simple and obvious as per documentation

What is less obvious is that you can use both together in the same `SELECT`, like in example below

```
WITH orders AS
  (SELECT 5 as order_id,
  "sprocket" as item_name,
  200 as quantity)
SELECT * EXCEPT (order_id) REPLACE ("widget" AS item_name), "more" as more_fields
FROM orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard @Markus' comment, not sure if this is exactly his request, but the functionality to drop duplicated column names from both tables **does** in fact seem to be working, e.g.

```
WITH
  CTE1 AS (
   SELECT TIME, "StringA" As Table_ID, Timestamp_Local , temperature_flow 
   FROM `yourtable1`
  ) ,
  CTE2 AS (
    SELECT  TIME, "StringB" As Table_ID, Timestamp_Local, vpp_average 
    FROM `yourtable2`
  ) 
SELECT * EXCEPT (Table_ID, Timestamp_Local ), 
   COALESCE(CTE1.Table_ID, CTE2.Table_ID) As M_Table_ID,
   COALESCE(CTE1.Timestamp_Local, CTE2.Timestamp_Local) As M_Timestamp  FROM
CTE1 FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2
USING(TIME) ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For example, Let's say you don't want a column from the table in CTE, then you can use a similar command.

```
with cte_table as ( SELECT * FROM 
        table1)
select  b.*, a.* EXCEPT (column_name(s))  from cte_table as a
        left join
        table2 as b
        on a.col1 = b.col1
```

Answer (score -1):

## Use case: Joining

As pointed out by the previous posts it is now possible to exclude columns from queries using the [`SELECT * EXCEPT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#select-except)-syntax.
Anyhow, the feature seems not entirely thought through as one of the crucial use cases to require such functionality is to *get rid of duplicate key-columns in joining while keeping one instance of the key-column*.

In other words: When joining `table_2` on `table_1` I want to keep the column used for joining only from `table_1`.

Especially for large tables this can be tedious if all columns except the desired are needed.
**E.g., what currently fails and would be desired:**

```sql
SELECT *
    EXCEPT(table_2.primary_key_column) -- -> Only exclude key-column from joined table
FROM table_1 AS table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS table_2 USING(primary_key_column)
```

This fails with a syntax error as the `table_2.` is not allowed in the `EXCEPT()`-clause...

---

## Workaround

While `EXCEPT()` excludes columns with the specified names from the "input"-tables it does not affect expressions within the select statement. In other words: If you specify the required column specifically from the respective table it will not be affected by `EXCEPT()`.

Thus, this allows us to work around our issue like in the example below.

```sql
SELECT
    table_1.primary_key_column AS primary_key_column -- -> Not affected
    , * 
    EXCEPT(primary_key_column)
FROM table_1 AS table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS table_2 USING(primary_key_column)
```

What is still not nice about this solution: Your column order is affected if your key-column is not in first place.

I hope it will get "fixed" in the future as it is not really user friendly and also does not seem very stringent.

Note: If you have **more than one join** you have to adjust the logic (as `EXCEPT()` only refers to the `*` in front of it), which also shows a solution closer to the shown use case issue:

```sql
SELECT
    table_1.* --> Includes primary_key_column
    , table_2.* EXCEPT(primary_key_column) --> Specifically excludes primary key from table_2
    , table_3.* EXCEPT(primary_key_column) --> Specifically excludes primary key from table_3
FROM table_1 AS table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS table_2 USING(primary_key_column)
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS table_3 USING(primary_key_column)
```