# Select all columns, but replace some with expression in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Similar to [Select All Columns Except Some in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056485/select-all-columns-except-some-in-google-bigquery) - we want to `SELECT *` from the table, but instead of excluding some columns, we want to replace them with some expression. For example, given table with columns: `name, start_date, amount, end_date, comment`, we want to convert `start` and `end` from `STRING` to `DATE`. It is possible to write

```
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT(start_date, end_date),
  CAST(start_date AS DATE) start_date,
  CAST(end_date AS DATE) end_date
```

But this would change order of columns moving start and end to the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to `SELECT * EXCEPT`, Google BigQuery also supports `SELECT * REPLACE` clause in Standard SQL dialect. Documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#select-list
Your example will become:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(
  CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
  CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date)
FROM T
```

Answer (score 9):

I would go further and say  - you can chain `EXCEPT` and `REPLACE` in same `SELECT`
It is not that obvious from documentation, so I thought it valuable

For example

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(end_date) REPLACE(
  CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date)
FROM T
```

This will remove `end_date` from output end replace original `start_date` with casted to date start_date