# How to transpose rows to columns with large amount of the data in BigQuery/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, google-bigquery, transpose

I have a problem in transposing a large amount of data table in BigQuery (1.5 billion rows) from rows to columns. I could figure out how to do it with small amount of data when hardcoded, but with this large amount. A snapshot of the table looks like this:

`+--------------------------+
| CustomerID Feature Value |
+--------------------------+
| 1 A123 3                 |
| 1 F213 7                 |
| 1 F231 8                 |
| 1 B789 9.1               |
| 2 A123 4                 |
| 2 U123 4                 |
| 2 B789 12                |
| .. .. ..                 |
| .. .. ..                 |
| 400000 A123 8            |
| 400000 U123 7            |
| 400000 R231 6            |
+--------------------------+`

So basically there are approximately 400,000 distinct customerID with 3000 features, and not every customerID has the same features, so some customerID may have 2000 features while some have 3000. The end result table I would like to get is each row presents one distinct customerID, and with 3000 columns that presents all the features. Like this:

`CustomerID Feature1 Feature2 ... Feature3000`

So some of the cells may have missing values.

Anyone has idea how to do this in BigQuery or SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
STEP #1
```

In below query replace `yourTable` with real name of your table and execute/run it

```
SELECT 'SELECT CustomerID, ' + 
   GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(
      'MAX(IF(Feature = "' + STRING(Feature) + '", Value, NULL))'
   ) 
   + ' FROM yourTable GROUP BY CustomerID'
FROM (SELECT Feature FROM yourTable GROUP BY Feature)
```

As a result you will get some string to be used in next step!

```
STEP #2
```

Take string you got from Step 1 and just execute it as a query
The output is a Pivot you asked in question

Comment: Thanks very much! I have tried and however, when I run the query from Step 2, I got an error saying "Resources exceeded during query execution." I guess it could due to the GROUP BY takes lots of memory. Is there a workaround on this?

Comment: I would recommend to start with limiting/lowering number of features. You can control this in Step 1 in subquery

Comment: If GROUP BY gives you trouble, try GROUP EACH BY

Comment: @Jade - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845697/how-to-scale-pivoting-in-bigquery for more recommendations to address "Resources exceeded during query execution." error

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Jade I posted a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu) before. And got a very helpful (and similar) answer from @MikhailBerlyant. For what it's worth, I had about 4000 features to dummify in my case and also ran into "Resources exceeded during query execution" error.

I think that this type of large-scale data transformation (rather than query) is better left for other tools more suitable for this task (such as Spark).