# Pivot data in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with BigQuery. I have two tables:

```
organisations:
  org_code STRING
  name STRING

spending:
  org STRING
  month DATE
  quantity INTEGER
  code STRING
```

And then quite a complicated query to get results by each organisation, by month:

```
SELECT
  organisations.org_code AS org,
  num.month AS month,
  (num.quantity / denom.quantity) AS ratio_quantity
FROM (
  SELECT
    org_code, name
  FROM
    [mytable.organisations]) AS organisations
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    org,
    month,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM
    [mytable.spending]
  GROUP BY
    org,
    month) AS denom
ON
  denom.org = organisations.org_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    org,
    month,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM
    [hscic.spending]
  WHERE
    code LIKE 'XXXX%'
  GROUP BY
    org,
    month) AS num
ON
  denom.month = num.month
  AND denom.org = num.org
ORDER BY org, month
```

My final results look like this, with a row per org/month combination:

```
org,month,ratio_quantity
A81001,2015-10-01 00:00:00 UTC,28
A82001,2015-11-01 00:00:00 UTC,43
A82002,2015-10-01 00:00:00 UTC,16
```

Now I would like to pivot the results to look like this, with one row per month, and one column per organisation:

```
month,items.A81001,items.A82002...
2015-10-01 00:00:00 UTC,28,16
2015-11-01 00:00:00 UTC,43,...
```

Is this possible in the same BigQuery call? Or should I create a new table and pivot it from there? Or should I just do the reshaping in Python?

UPDATE: There are about 500,000 results, fyi.

Comment: A query that mimics the pandas.melt() function without using UDFs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057616/13632099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q. Is this possible in the same BigQuery call? Or should I create a new
>   table and pivot it from there?

In general, you can use that “complicated query” as a subquery for extra logic to be applied to your current result.
So, it is definitely doable. But code can quickly become un-manageable or hard to manage – so you can consider writing this result into new table and then pivot it from there

If you stuck with direction of doing pivot (the way you described in your question) - check below link to see detailed intro on how you can implement pivot within BigQuery.
[How to scale Pivoting in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845697/how-to-scale-pivoting-in-bigquery/34845698#34845698)
Please note – there is a limitation of 10K columns per table - so you are limited with 10K organizations.
You can also see below as simplified examples (if above one is too complex/verbose):
[How to transpose rows to columns with large amount of the data in BigQuery/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798244/how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-with-large-amount-of-the-data-in-bigquery-sql/34798760#34798760)
[How to create dummy variable columns for thousands of categories in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu/34010803#34010803)
[Pivot Repeated fields in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768448/pivot-repeated-fields-in-bigquery/33769831#33769831)

> Q. Or should I just do the reshaping in Python?

If above will not work for you – pivoting on client is always an option but now you should consider client side limitations

Hope this helped!