# BigQuery repeat same subquery 50x times on 50 different tables in a function

Tags: google-bigquery

Apologies in advance for the wall of text. There is a lot of repetitive code here, and the post is not as long as it seems.

I previously posted [a related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776635/bigquery-reshape-table-with-structs-from-wide-to-long) on this, which was helpful but now I've got a separate use-case for reshaping. I have a table that is far too wide with too many structs to manually reshape it. Instead, I have an approach where I am (a) manually selecting each of the nested structs from my table, (b) reshaping it (and adding a few other columns), and (c) `UNION ALL`'ing them back together. Parts (a) and (b) look something like this:

```
WITH 
  t1_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t1.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t2_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t2.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t3_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t3.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t4_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t4.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t5_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t5.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),

  t1_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t1.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t2_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t2.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t3_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t3.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t4_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t4.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t5_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t5.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),

  -- Need to reshape EACH of the underlying structs
  t1_o_long as (
    SELECT 
      season, game, team, true as is_o, 't1' as table_name, metric, SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) value
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        season, game, team,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], r'^"|"$', '') metric, 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r'^"|"$', '') value
      FROM t1_o,
      UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_json_string(t1_o), r'{|}', ''))) pair
    )
    WHERE NOT LOWER(metric) IN ('season', 'game', 'team')
  ),

  t2_o_long as (
    SELECT 
      season, game, team, true as is_o, 't2' as table_name, metric, SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) value
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        season, game, team,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], r'^"|"$', '') metric, 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r'^"|"$', '') value
      FROM t2_o,
      UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_json_string(t2_o), r'{|}', ''))) pair
    )
    WHERE NOT LOWER(metric) IN ('season', 'game', 'team')
  ),

  ...
```

My question is - is it possible to create a function, let's call it wideToLong, that would allow me to do the following:

```
WITH 
  t1_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t1.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t2_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t2.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t3_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t3.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t4_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t4.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t5_o as (SELECT season, game, team, t5.o.* FROM `mydatabase`),

  t1_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t1.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t2_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t2.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t3_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t3.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t4_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t4.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),
  t5_d as (SELECT season, game, team, t5.d.* FROM `mydatabase`),

  -- Need to reshape EACH of the underlying structs
  t1_o_long as (wideToLong(table = t1_o, is_o = true, name = 't1')),
  t2_o_long as (wideToLong(table = t2_o, is_o = true, name = 't2')),
  t3_o_long as (wideToLong(table = t3_o, is_o = true, name = 't3')),
  t4_o_long as (wideToLong(table = t4_o, is_o = true, name = 't4')),
  t5_o_long as (wideToLong(table = t5_o, is_o = true, name = 't5')),
  t1_d_long as (wideToLong(table = t1_d, is_o = false, name = 't1')),
  t2_d_long as (wideToLong(table = t2_d, is_o = false, name = 't2')),
  t3_d_long as (wideToLong(table = t3_d, is_o = false, name = 't3')),
  t4_d_long as (wideToLong(table = t4_d, is_o = false, name = 't4')),
  t5_d_long as (wideToLong(table = t5_d, is_o = false, name = 't5'))
  ...
```

... where wideToLong encompasses the reshaping functionality:

```
    SELECT 
      season, game, team, true as is_o, 't1' as table_name, metric, SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) value
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        season, game, team,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], r'^"|"$', '') metric, 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r'^"|"$', '') value
      FROM t1_o,
      UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_json_string(t1_o), r'{|}', ''))) pair
    )
    WHERE NOT LOWER(metric) IN ('season', 'game', 'team')
  )
```

Per the previous stackoverflow post, I could save the table in legacy mode first to flatten it, but (a) i'd like to add additional columns to the reshaped data (is_o, and table_name), (b) I'd like to understand if this ability to create functions for repetitive tasks like this is possible, and (c) saving the table in legacy mode is okay for a 1-time reshaping but doesn't fit well into the daily data pipeline that my company uses. Learning how to create a function for this repetitive task would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you union the <season, game, team, <struct>> CTEs first?  Then you only have to do the 'wideToLong' on the unioned table (1 time) and not many times?

Comment: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, etc. are each very different tables.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to create a function, let's call it wideToLong, that would allow me to do the following ?

UDFs (User-Defined Functions) accepts [columns as input, and return values](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#top_of_page). Your wideToLong function is expecting to receive a table as parameter, and return another table, which is not supported in BigQuery yet. You could try manipulating the tables to use them as an array of structs, but it would probably make it overall really complex to manage.

You mentioned that the tables are very different, so, my suggestion is to work with the structs (t1.o.*, t2.d.*, ...) to transform them into something that you can later be able to UNION and "wideToLong" just once.