# Convert Long table to wide table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table like this:

[image]

Required Output is :

[image]

**Note :** The keys in Extended_property_key column are not fixed, it keeps on adding frequently. Hence the columns in Output will also keep on adding.

I need to build a Bigquery which can handle dynamic adding of columns in output query along with pivoting.

Comment: Can anyone help on above issue. I have tried many options given which makes use of ANY_VALUE() aggregate function but that is something I am not looking for.

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187840/9928809) explaining different approaches in Biqgquery pivoting techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT account_id, ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT "MAX(IF(Extended_property_key = '" || Extended_property_key || "', Extended_property_value, NULL)) AS " || Extended_property_key)
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) || '''  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
'''
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row account_id  Key1    Key2    Key3     
1   1           Value1  null    null     
2   7           null    Value2  Value3
```

Comment: I am looking to parameterising the above query as the same table exists for many operators . example - dataset1.table1 , dataset2.table1 , dataset3.table1. 
In this case I would like to make the above query as a template query  with pivot  key and table name to be passed as parameters. Such that the same query can be used for multiple operators.
I tried using Airflow BigQueryOperator but this operator does not provide parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
CALL fhoffa.x.pivot(
  'p.d.t1' # source table
  , 'p.d.t2' # destination table
  , ['ACCOUNT_ID'] # row_ids
  , 'EXTENDED_PROPERTY_KEY' # pivot_col_name
  , 'EXTENDED_PROPERTY_VALUE' # pivot_col_value
  , 30 # max_columns
  , 'ANY_VALUE' # aggregation
  , '' # optional_limit
);
```

More details on how to pivot:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710

Comment: Thanks for this link . I understand that in this step , using aggregate function you are fetching distinct values and the outer query is looping over those values. 
I am trying to create the exact query without string concatenation but I am getting errors due to quotes I am missing.


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
    "SELECT STRING_AGG(' "||aggregation
    ||"""(IF('||@pivot_col_name||'="'||x.value||'", '||@pivot_col_value||', null)) e_'||fhoffa.x.normalize_col_name(x.value))
   FROM UNNEST((
       SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT("""||pivot_col_name||", @max_columns) FROM `"||table_name||"`)) x"
  )

Comment: Please post a new question so we have enough space to look at the code and fix it :)

Comment: I have posted a new question here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659762/facing-issue-while-calling-bigquery-stored-procedure

Please check and provide explaination about the underlying query which runs in stored procedure link of yours