# Facing Issue in understanding BigQuery Stored Procedure used in pivoting

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do pivoting using BigQuery Stored Procedure like explained in this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710)

Input Table:
[image]

Output Required:
[image]

First part of stored procedure is to generate list of all values which are to be used to generate new columns like below :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
    "SELECT STRING_AGG(' "||aggregation
    ||"""(IF('||@pivot_col_name||'="'||x.value||'", '||@pivot_col_value||', null)) '||x.value)
   FROM UNNEST((
       SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT("""||pivot_col_name||", @max_columns) FROM `"||table_name||"`)) x"
  ) INTO header_pivot 
  USING pivot_col_name AS pivot_col_name, pivot_col_value AS pivot_col_value, max_columns AS max_columns;
```

This query is generating output :

```
MAX(IF(EXTENDED_PROPERTY_KEY="key1", EXTENDED_PROPERTY_VALUE, null)) key1, 
MAX(IF(EXTENDED_PROPERTY_KEY="key2", EXTENDED_PROPERTY_VALUE, null)) key2,
MAX(IF(EXTENDED_PROPERTY_KEY="key3", EXTENDED_PROPERTY_VALUE, null)) key3, 
MAX(IF(EXTENDED_PROPERTY_KEY="key4", EXTENDED_PROPERTY_VALUE, null)) key4
```

The second part :

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(''||(i+1)) FROM UNNEST(row_ids) WITH OFFSET i
```

Here I am  facing difficulty as offset value is not increasing by 1 for each row_ids[Account_id]

The approach did work for me though with some manipulation but I wanted to understand the underlying query which generates the desired output . I tried to break it down and reached the final query as

```
SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(x) FROM UNNEST([row_ids]) x) # this part extracts individual row_ids ,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT "MAX(IF(pivot_key= '" || pivot_key|| "', pivot_value, NULL)) AS " || pivot_key)
        FROM `project.dataset.table`
          ) # generates string for each key of pivot_key column
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY (SELECT STRING_AGG(''||(i+1)) FROM UNNEST([row_ids]) WITH OFFSET i) # generates offset for each row_id , though in this case I see it is always 1
ORDER BY (SELECT STRING_AGG(''||(i+1)) FROM UNNEST([row_ids]) WITH OFFSET i)
```

But when I try to run the above concatenated query it fails at

a) `SELECT STRING_AGG(x) FROM UNNEST([row_ids]) x)` saying that STRING_AGG() should have String values , in my case row_id is integer ,  so for that I manipulated it as `SELECT STRING_AGG('' || x) FROM UNNEST([row_ids]) x)`

b) After fixing a) it again fails saying `UNNEST expression references column row_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated`

Additinally :

Row_Id == Account_Id

Pivot_key == Extended_Property_Key

Pivot_value == Extended_Property_Value

Please explain what is the missing portion here ?

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa - Could you help me in elaborating the stored procedure creation. I understand the working but  finding difficulty in getting to know the query which runs  when procedure is called. I tried to interpret the query (above)  but facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

The final query executed in your case probably is:

```
SELECT
  account_id,
  MAX(
  IF
    (extended_property_key="Key 3",
      extended_property_value,
      NULL)) e_Key3,
  MAX(
  IF
    (extended_property_key="Key 2",
      extended_property_value,
      NULL)) e_Key2,
  MAX(
  IF
    (extended_property_key="Key 1",
      extended_property_value,
      NULL)) e_Key1
FROM
  `your-table`
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1
```

Keep in mind that this just a static query created by that script. Pivoting tables programmatically using normal `SQL` is not possible in `BigQuery`

Comment: Thanks for replying and I understand the limitations of  static query too. That's the reason i went ahead with dynamic approach in the link above so that I can use and manipulate as per the my requirement .
To make it clear I have tagged the column names used in sample data with variables I am replacing in query

Comment: What exactly do you need?