# BigQuery Pivot Data Rows Columns (in STANDARD SQL, no hardcoding)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

looking for a solution similar to this:

[BigQuery Pivot Data Rows Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807572/bigquery-pivot-data-rows-columns)

except using standard SQL and no hardcoding.

Comment: Any particular reason or use-case you are doing this?  BigQuery stores data in columns, so adding more columns is often not the best solution.  Other applications  that read your data (Looker, Tableau, Excel, Python, R) can often handle pivoting in a much easier fashion.

Comment: Closing because Mikhail's answer linked in the question is one of the best available answers for this problem for now.