# Dynamically creating columns from row data using Select in Bigquery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

**Background**

I want to rename my case statement in sql select statement dynamically.

Eg:

`SELECT (case when id= x.id then x.sums end) x.id
 as  (select id,count(*) sums from table`
`group by id) x`

what i want the output is list of columns created ,with Labels as distinct id's from "id" column.

However,this variable **x.id**  is not dynamically outputing values,rather i get output a single column x.id.

Eg:

Columns in table...

### id---c1----c2

---

1----x1---x2

2----x2----x3

3----x4----x5

columns expected after running query...

### 1-----2----3

---

but actual o/p column is::

### x.id

---

**Query**
Any ideas,how to generate columns dynamically using select query,please correct me ,if i am wrong.

Comment: having example of input table and desired columns of output - can you clarify what values in rows you expect to see? it is not clear!

Comment: Look up `early binding` vs `late binding`.  The very concept behind this won't work; a field's value can not be used as a field name *(or table name, etc, etc)*.  If you want dynamical number of columns or dynamic field names then you need one query to read the names you want, then code to write the sql to use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery!

Please note: your expectations about output column names are not correct!
Column name cannot start with digit - so in below example  - i will be using id_1, id_2 and id_3 instead of 1, 2 and 3

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS id_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS id_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS id_3
FROM YourTable
```

Above example assumes you know in advance your IDs and there are very few of them so it is not a big deal to write manually few numbers of lines with SUM(...) for each id

If this is not a case  - you can first generate above query programmatically by running below query

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' + 
   GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN id = ' + STRING(id) + ' THEN 1 END) AS id_' + STRING(id)
   ) 
   + ' FROM YourTable'
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM YourTable GROUP BY id ORDER BY id
)
```

as a result - you will get string like below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS id_1,SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS id_2,SUM(CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS id_3 FROM YourTable
```

So, now just copy it and paste into Query Editor and run it

you can see similar example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623258/5221944

Comment: Hi Mikhail, is there an equivalent function for standard SQL?

Comment: @JoeChan - please post your question and I will be happy to answer it. note: it is hard to figure out what exactly your are asking when you do this in comments and even if I would got it  - no way to answer within the comment. so post your question please as a new question