# Transform a Bigquery Table with variable columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a pivot sort of thing for a group of customer ids (cids).The dataset is of the form

| Cid | Match |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |

The transformed dataset should look like

| Cid | Match_1 | Match_2 | Match_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | null |
| B | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Here the Match_n suffix is dynamic and should be decided based on the max rows present across all Cids. I am not sure if this is even feasible.

I have tried pivot and other things but eventually hit a wall.

Found this but this is for a specific range of i ([Big Query Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616286/big-query-transpose/36623258#36623258)).

P.S: I just thought of something! Maybe that works. But still currently need help.

Comment: please share all the code that you have tried

Comment: `Match_2` at first row in your expected output shouldn't be `2` by any chance ?  And order of column value is significant ? I mean For `B`, `3, 2, 4` or `4, 3, 2` is possible output? or you're just expecting them sorted ?

Answer (score 0):

> Match_n suffix is dynamic and should be decided based on the max rows present across all Cids.

I think you should consider a dynamic SQL along with `PIVOT` query.

```sql
-- sample data
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT Cid, Match 
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('AABBB','')) Cid WITH offset 
  JOIN UNNEST([1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) Match WITH offset USING(offset);

-- query starts here  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cid ORDER BY Match) rn FROM sample_table)
   PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Match) Match FOR rn IN (%s))
""", (
  SELECT STRING_AGG('' || n, ',') 
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(
                  1,
                  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample_table 
                    GROUP BY Cid ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1)
               )) n
  ));
```

**Query Result**

[image]