# convert rows into columns - Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like as shown below

[image]

As shown, I have two rows for the same subject. each row indicating a day

However, I wish to convert them into a single row like as shown below

[image]

Can you help? I did check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761453/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-pivot-implementation/40766540#40766540) but unable to translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761453/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-pivot-implementation/40766540#40766540) but unable to translate it?

Let's first transform your original data into form that we then can pivot

Below does this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, balance, 
  DATE_DIFF(day, MIN(day) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id), DAY) + 1 delta
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
-- ORDER BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, delta
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row subject_id  hm_id   icu_id  balance delta    
1   124         ab      cd      2       1    
2   124         ab      cd      5       2    
3   321         xy      pq      -6      1    
4   321         xy      pq      1       2
```

So, now we need to pivot this based on delta column - balance for delta = 1 will go to day_1_balance, balance for delta = 2 will go to day_2_balance and so on

Let's for now assume that there are just two deltas (as in your sample data). In this simplified case  - below will make a trick

```
#standardSQL
SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id,
  MAX(IF(delta = 1, balance, NULL)) day_1_balance,
  MAX(IF(delta = 2, balance, NULL)) day_2_balance  
FROM (
  SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, balance, 
    DATE_DIFF(day, MIN(day) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id), DAY) + 1 delta
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
GROUP BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id
-- ORDER BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id
```

with result

```
Row subject_id  hm_id   icu_id  day_1_balance   day_2_balance    
1   124         ab      cd      2               5    
2   321         xy      pq      -6              1
```

Obviously, in real case you don't know how many delta columns you have so you need to build above query dynamically - and that is exactly where [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761453/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-pivot-implementation/40766540#40766540) you referenced - will help you

You can try again by yourself - or see below for final solution

**Step 1** - generating query

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, balance, 
    DATE_DIFF(day, MIN(day) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id), DAY) + 1 delta
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id,', 
   STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(' MAX(IF(delta = ',CAST(delta AS STRING),', balance, NULL)) as day_',CAST(delta AS STRING),'_balance')
   ) 
   ,' FROM temp GROUP BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id ORDER BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id')
FROM (
  SELECT delta 
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY delta
  ORDER BY delta
)
```

Result of step 1 is the text that represent final query that you need to run as step 2

**Step 2** - run generated query

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, balance, 
    DATE_DIFF(day, MIN(day) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id), DAY) + 1 delta
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
SELECT subject_id, hm_id, icu_id, 
  MAX(IF(delta = 1, balance, NULL)) AS day_1_balance, 
  MAX(IF(delta = 2, balance, NULL)) AS day_2_balance 
FROM temp 
GROUP BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id 
-- ORDER BY subject_id, hm_id, icu_id
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try.  Upvoted. Your expertise in big query is admirable. Most of the questions in forums has your answer

Comment: would you be able to help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303177/rowwise-maximum-value-of-n-columns-elegant-way-using-bigquery-postgresql

Comment: sure. just did :o)