# rowwise maximum value (of n columns) - Elegant approach

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table like as shown below

[image]

I was trying the below but it certainly isn't elegant and efficient. Is this the only way to do?

I am looking for ways to do this in both **Bigquery and Postgresql**

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN date_1 >= date_2 AND date_1 >= date_3 AND date_1 >= date_4 AND date_1 >= date_5 AND date_1 >= date_6 THEN date_1
    WHEN date_2 >= date_1 AND date_2 >= date_3 AND date_2 >= date_4 AND date_2 >= date_5 AND date_2 >= date_6 end AS max_date
from table_1
```

And I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: All the solutions given below works and are useful in my work. However I can mark only one and I go with @khan's answer, as it is simple and easy to follow. Nonetheless, all other answers give expected output and are up-voted. I appreciate all of their time and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be good and work in both BigQuery/PGSQL environments:

```
select 
   subject_id,
   hadm_id,
   icustay_id,
   greatest(
      coalesce(date_1, '1900/01/01'), 
      coalesce(date_2, '1900/01/01'), 
      coalesce(date_3, '1900/01/01')
      coalesce(date_4, '1900/01/01'),
      coalesce(date_5, '1900/01/01'),
      coalesce(date_6, '1900/01/01')
   ) as max_date
from `dataset.table`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But can't we use group by? Usually `Max` has to be followed by group by. But doesn't `greatest` work that way?

Comment: Your solution works though. But curious to know what's the difference between `max` and `greatest`.

Comment: @SSMK - MAX is an aggregate function that performs a calculation on a set of values. COUNT, MIN and MAX are examples of aggregate functions. While GREATEST is a mathematical function over list of values

Comment: Thank you @MikhailBerlyant for your help and answers in the forum

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL you can use the `GREATEST` expression:

```
SELECT GREATEST(date_1, date_2, date_3, date_4, date_5, date_6) AS max_date
...
```

Since that is not standard SQL, it probably won't work in other databases.

At any rate, you can reduce the number of comparisons, since the second `WHEN` expression of a `CASE` statement is only tested if the first was not `TRUE`:

```
CASE
   WHEN date_1 >= date_2 AND date_1 >= date_3 AND date_1 >= date_4 AND date_1 >= date_5 AND date_1 >= date_6
   THEN date_1
   WHEN date_2 >= date_3 AND date_2 >= date_4 AND date_2 >= date_5 AND date_2 >= date_6
   THEN date_2
   WHEN date_3 >= date_4 AND date_3 >= date_5 AND date_3 >= date_6
   THEN date_3
   WHEN date_4 >= date_5 AND date_4 >= date_6
   THEN date_4
   WHEN date_5 >= date_6
   THEN date_5
   ELSE date_6
END
```

I don't know if you consider that more elegant, but instead of the `AND` clauses you could also use `ALL` with a `VALUES` expression:

```
WHEN date_1 >= ALL (VALUES (date_2), (date_3), (date_4), (date_5), (date_6))
THEN date_1
...
```

Comment: Currently traveling. But may I check whether `ALL (VALUES...` works in Bigquery?

Comment: I don't know. It is standard SQL though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id,
    (
    SELECT Max(v) 
    FROM (VALUES (date_1), (date_2), (date_3),(date_4),(date_5),(date_6)) AS value(v)
    ) as max_date    
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is as following. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=80049742d82586a48cc8eed93fc35fc7)

```
WITH table_2 AS (
SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_1 AS date_x FROM table_1
UNION ALL SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_2 AS date_x FROM table_1
UNION ALL SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_3 AS date_x FROM table_1
UNION ALL SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_4 AS date_x FROM table_1
UNION ALL SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_5 AS date_x FROM table_1
UNION ALL SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,date_6 AS date_x FROM table_1
)
SELECT subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id,MAX(date_x) FROM table_2
GROUP BY subject_id,hadm_id,icust_ay_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for **BigQuery Standard SQL** and with few assumptions about your sampled data: you data_N columns are of DATE type and thus empty values are actually NULLs. In this you can use below to find max date across columns in the row

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(date_1, date_2, date_3, date_4, date_5, date_6), 
  (SELECT MAX(val) FROM UNNEST(
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', [date_1, date_2, date_3, date_4, date_5, date_6]), r'[\[\] ]', ''))
    ) val
    WHERE val != 'NULL'
  ) max_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

In case if your date_N columns are of STRING type you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(date_1, date_2, date_3, date_4, date_5, date_6), 
  (SELECT MAX(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', val)) FROM UNNEST(
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', [date_1, date_2, date_3, date_4, date_5, date_6]), r'[\[\] ]', ''))) val
    WHERE val != ''
  ) max_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```