# How to unnest and pivot two columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a BQ table containing the following information

| id | test.name | test.score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
|  | b | 7 |
| 2 | a | 8 |
|  | c | 3 |

Where test is nested. How would I pivot test into the following table?

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |  |
| 2 | 8 |  | 3 |

I cannot pivot test directly, as I get the following error message at `pivot(test)`: `Table-valued function not found`. Previous questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761453/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-pivot-implementation)) don't deal with nested columns or are outdated.

The following query looks like a useful first step:

```
select a.id, t
from `table` as a,
unnest(test) as t
```

However, this just provides me with:

| id | test.name | test.score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 1 | b | 7 |
| 2 | a | 8 |
| 2 | c | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is generic/dynamic way to handle your case

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
  SELECT id, """ || 
    STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(name = '""" || name || """', score, NULL)) AS """ || name, ', ') 
  || """
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t, t.test
  GROUP BY id
  """
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t, t.test
    ORDER BY name
  )
);
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row     id      a       b       c    
1       1       5       7       null     
2       2       8       null    3
```

Answer (score 5):

Conditional aggregation is a good approach.  If your tables are large, you might find that this has the best performance:

```
select t.id,
       (select max(tt.score) from unnest(t.score) tt where tt.name = 'a') as a,
       (select max(tt.score) from unnest(t.score) tt where tt.name = 'b') as b,
       (select max(tt.score) from unnest(t.score) tt where tt.name = 'c') as c
from `table` t;
```

The reason I recommend this is because it avoids the outer aggregation.  The `unnest()` happens without shuffling the data around -- and I have found that this is a big win in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using conditional aggregation

```
select id, 
       max(case when test.name='a' then test.score end) as a,
       max(case when test.name='b' then test.score end) as b,
       max(case when test.name='c' then test.score end) as c
from 
(
select a.id, t
from `table` as a,
unnest(test) as t
)A group by id
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is already a great step, but the number of rows in each test could be different for each id and will at least change over time. Could this be done dynamically?

Comment: @ThomasW, you can check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery for the dynamic build