# Transpose rows and column when you dont have any 'id' type column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

I want to Transpose columns and rows when you don't have a unique id type column in BigQuery.

I have large number of rows. Date values are unique for each month-year going over couple of years.

Columns:

```
date    total_count_of_customer total_revenue   new_customer_count  new_customer_revenue    churn_count churn_revenue   flat_count  flat_revenue    returning_count returning_revenue   expansion_mrr   expansion_count contraction_mrr contraction_count
```

I want to swap 'date' column values to column and rest of the columns to rows.

Sample Data:

```
date    total_count_of_customer total_revenue   new_customer_count  new_customer_revenue    churn_count churn_revenue   flat_count  flat_revenue    returning_count returning_revenue   expansion_mrr   contraction_mrr
7/1/11  756 18627.91    518.33  11505.81    188.00  -4333.50    2015.00 47057.36    -267.33 -5848.13    682.46  -962.85
8/1/11  45645   27691.1 562.83  12517.54    217.50  -5045.38    2388.50 55845.24    -365.33 -8066.40    597.02  -1114.54
9/1/11  3445    35502.98    607.33  13529.26    247.00  -5757.26    2762.00 64633.11    -463.33 -10284.67   511.57  -1266.22
```

Output:

```
                     7/1/11 8/1/11  9/1/11
total_count_of_customer 756 45645   3445
total_revenue   18627.91    27691.1 35502.98
new_customer_count  518.33  562.83  607.33
new_customer_revenue    11505.81    12517.54    13529.26
churn_count 188.00  217.50  247.00
churn_revenue   -4333.50    -5045.38    -5757.26
flat_count  2015.00 2388.50 2762.00
flat_revenue    47057.36    55845.24    64633.11
returning_count -267.33 -365.33 -463.33
returning_revenue   -5848.13    -8066.40    -10284.67
expansion_mrr   682.46  597.02  511.57
contraction_mrr -962.85 -1114.54    -1266.22
```

I referenced this article but i dont have any unique ID in my case: [How to transpose rows to columns with large amount of the data in BigQuery/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798244/how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-with-large-amount-of-the-data-in-bigquery-sql/34798760#34798760)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: Done as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '7/1/11' `date`, 756 total_count_of_customer, 18627.91 total_revenue, 518.33 new_customer_count, 11505.81 new_customer_revenue, 188.00 churn_count, -4333.50 churn_revenue, 2015.00 flat_count, 47057.36 flat_revenue, -267.33 returning_count, -5848.13 returning_revenue, 682.46 expansion_mrr, -962.85 contraction_mrr UNION ALL
  SELECT '8/1/11', 45645, 27691.1, 562.83, 12517.54, 217.50, -5045.38, 2388.50, 55845.24, -365.33, -8066.40, 597.02, -1114.54 UNION ALL
  SELECT '9/1/11', 3445, 35502.98, 607.33, 13529.26, 247.00, -5757.26, 2762.00, 64633.11, -463.33, -10284.67, 511.57, -1266.22 
), temp AS (
  SELECT x id, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value
  FROM (
    SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) x
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  ), 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(x, r'[{}"]', ''))) kv
), flatten AS (
  SELECT b.key, b.value value, a.value `date`
  FROM temp a
  JOIN temp b
  USING(id) 
  WHERE a.key = 'date'
  AND b.key != 'date'
)
SELECT 
  key,
  MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/11', value, NULL)) date_7_1_11,
  MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/11', value, NULL)) date_8_1_11,
  MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/11', value, NULL)) date_9_1_11
FROM flatten
GROUP BY key
```

with result

[image]

So, obviously (as you mentioned - you have few years of monthly data) it is up to you now how to proceed from that point. You can either manually add lines in above SELECT statement - one line per month (in case of 3 years - it will be 36 lines so not that big deal but boring) or you can now reuse technique described in my another answer that you mentioned in your question - [How to transpose rows to columns with large amount of the data in BigQuery/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798244/how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-with-large-amount-of-the-data-in-bigquery-sql/34798760#34798760)

> I have years from 2011 to 2019 for now now and will keep on growing in future. ... It will be helpful if you can also describe the solution mentioned in that link if that is possible

**Step 1**: prepare SELECT Statement covering 2011 - 2019 years

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-01-01', INTERVAL i - 1 MONTH) month
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 9*12)) i
), temp AS (
  SELECT 
    FORMAT('%i/%i/%i', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month), EXTRACT(DAY FROM month), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month) - 2000) month,
    FORMAT('date_%i_%i_%i', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month), EXTRACT(DAY FROM month), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month) - 2000) column  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`   
)
SELECT
  CONCAT('SELECT key,', STRING_AGG(CONCAT("MAX(IF(`date`='", month, "',value,NULL)) ", column, "")), ' FROM flatten GROUP BY key')
FROM temp
```

above will return below STRING

```sql
SELECT key,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/11',value,NULL)) date_1_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/11',value,NULL)) date_2_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/11',value,NULL)) date_3_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/11',value,NULL)) date_4_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/11',value,NULL)) date_5_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/11',value,NULL)) date_6_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/11',value,NULL)) date_7_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/11',value,NULL)) date_8_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/11',value,NULL)) date_9_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/11',value,NULL)) date_10_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/11',value,NULL)) date_11_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/11',value,NULL)) date_12_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/12',value,NULL)) date_1_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/12',value,NULL)) date_2_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/12',value,NULL)) date_3_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/12',value,NULL)) date_4_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/12',value,NULL)) date_5_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/12',value,NULL)) date_6_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/12',value,NULL)) date_7_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/12',value,NULL)) date_8_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/12',value,NULL)) date_9_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/12',value,NULL)) date_10_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/12',value,NULL)) date_11_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/12',value,NULL)) date_12_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/13',value,NULL)) date_1_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/13',value,NULL)) date_2_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/13',value,NULL)) date_3_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/13',value,NULL)) date_4_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/13',value,NULL)) date_5_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/13',value,NULL)) date_6_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/13',value,NULL)) date_7_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/13',value,NULL)) date_8_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/13',value,NULL)) date_9_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/13',value,NULL)) date_10_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/13',value,NULL)) date_11_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/13',value,NULL)) date_12_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/14',value,NULL)) date_1_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/14',value,NULL)) date_2_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/14',value,NULL)) date_3_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/14',value,NULL)) date_4_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/14',value,NULL)) date_5_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/14',value,NULL)) date_6_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/14',value,NULL)) date_7_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/14',value,NULL)) date_8_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/14',value,NULL)) date_9_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/14',value,NULL)) date_10_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/14',value,NULL)) date_11_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/14',value,NULL)) date_12_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/15',value,NULL)) date_1_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/15',value,NULL)) date_2_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/15',value,NULL)) date_3_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/15',value,NULL)) date_4_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/15',value,NULL)) date_5_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/15',value,NULL)) date_6_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/15',value,NULL)) date_7_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/15',value,NULL)) date_8_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/15',value,NULL)) date_9_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/15',value,NULL)) date_10_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/15',value,NULL)) date_11_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/15',value,NULL)) date_12_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/16',value,NULL)) date_1_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/16',value,NULL)) date_2_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/16',value,NULL)) date_3_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/16',value,NULL)) date_4_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/16',value,NULL)) date_5_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/16',value,NULL)) date_6_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/16',value,NULL)) date_7_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/16',value,NULL)) date_8_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/16',value,NULL)) date_9_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/16',value,NULL)) date_10_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/16',value,NULL)) date_11_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/16',value,NULL)) date_12_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/17',value,NULL)) date_1_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/17',value,NULL)) date_2_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/17',value,NULL)) date_3_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/17',value,NULL)) date_4_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/17',value,NULL)) date_5_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/17',value,NULL)) date_6_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/17',value,NULL)) date_7_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/17',value,NULL)) date_8_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/17',value,NULL)) date_9_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/17',value,NULL)) date_10_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/17',value,NULL)) date_11_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/17',value,NULL)) date_12_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/18',value,NULL)) date_1_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/18',value,NULL)) date_2_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/18',value,NULL)) date_3_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/18',value,NULL)) date_4_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/18',value,NULL)) date_5_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/18',value,NULL)) date_6_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/18',value,NULL)) date_7_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/18',value,NULL)) date_8_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/18',value,NULL)) date_9_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/18',value,NULL)) date_10_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/18',value,NULL)) date_11_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/18',value,NULL)) date_12_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/19',value,NULL)) date_1_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/19',value,NULL)) date_2_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/19',value,NULL)) date_3_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/19',value,NULL)) date_4_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/19',value,NULL)) date_5_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/19',value,NULL)) date_6_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/19',value,NULL)) date_7_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/19',value,NULL)) date_8_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/19',value,NULL)) date_9_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/19',value,NULL)) date_10_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/19',value,NULL)) date_11_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/19',value,NULL)) date_12_1_19 FROM flatten GROUP BY key
```

**Step 2**: Copy that string and replace SELECT statement in original answer. You should get below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '7/1/11' `date`, 756 total_count_of_customer, 18627.91 total_revenue, 518.33 new_customer_count, 11505.81 new_customer_revenue, 188.00 churn_count, -4333.50 churn_revenue, 2015.00 flat_count, 47057.36 flat_revenue, -267.33 returning_count, -5848.13 returning_revenue, 682.46 expansion_mrr, -962.85 contraction_mrr UNION ALL
  SELECT '8/1/11', 45645, 27691.1, 562.83, 12517.54, 217.50, -5045.38, 2388.50, 55845.24, -365.33, -8066.40, 597.02, -1114.54 UNION ALL
  SELECT '9/1/11', 3445, 35502.98, 607.33, 13529.26, 247.00, -5757.26, 2762.00, 64633.11, -463.33, -10284.67, 511.57, -1266.22 
), temp AS (
  SELECT x id, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value
  FROM (
    SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) x
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  ), 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(x, r'[{}"]', ''))) kv
), flatten AS (
  SELECT b.key, b.value value, a.value `date`
  FROM temp a
  JOIN temp b
  USING(id) 
  WHERE a.key = 'date'
  AND b.key != 'date'
)
SELECT key,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/11',value,NULL)) date_1_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/11',value,NULL)) date_2_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/11',value,NULL)) date_3_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/11',value,NULL)) date_4_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/11',value,NULL)) date_5_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/11',value,NULL)) date_6_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/11',value,NULL)) date_7_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/11',value,NULL)) date_8_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/11',value,NULL)) date_9_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/11',value,NULL)) date_10_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/11',value,NULL)) date_11_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/11',value,NULL)) date_12_1_11,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/12',value,NULL)) date_1_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/12',value,NULL)) date_2_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/12',value,NULL)) date_3_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/12',value,NULL)) date_4_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/12',value,NULL)) date_5_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/12',value,NULL)) date_6_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/12',value,NULL)) date_7_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/12',value,NULL)) date_8_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/12',value,NULL)) date_9_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/12',value,NULL)) date_10_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/12',value,NULL)) date_11_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/12',value,NULL)) date_12_1_12,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/13',value,NULL)) date_1_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/13',value,NULL)) date_2_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/13',value,NULL)) date_3_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/13',value,NULL)) date_4_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/13',value,NULL)) date_5_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/13',value,NULL)) date_6_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/13',value,NULL)) date_7_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/13',value,NULL)) date_8_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/13',value,NULL)) date_9_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/13',value,NULL)) date_10_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/13',value,NULL)) date_11_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/13',value,NULL)) date_12_1_13,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/14',value,NULL)) date_1_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/14',value,NULL)) date_2_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/14',value,NULL)) date_3_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/14',value,NULL)) date_4_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/14',value,NULL)) date_5_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/14',value,NULL)) date_6_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/14',value,NULL)) date_7_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/14',value,NULL)) date_8_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/14',value,NULL)) date_9_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/14',value,NULL)) date_10_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/14',value,NULL)) date_11_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/14',value,NULL)) date_12_1_14,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/15',value,NULL)) date_1_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/15',value,NULL)) date_2_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/15',value,NULL)) date_3_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/15',value,NULL)) date_4_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/15',value,NULL)) date_5_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/15',value,NULL)) date_6_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/15',value,NULL)) date_7_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/15',value,NULL)) date_8_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/15',value,NULL)) date_9_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/15',value,NULL)) date_10_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/15',value,NULL)) date_11_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/15',value,NULL)) date_12_1_15,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/16',value,NULL)) date_1_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/16',value,NULL)) date_2_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/16',value,NULL)) date_3_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/16',value,NULL)) date_4_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/16',value,NULL)) date_5_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/16',value,NULL)) date_6_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/16',value,NULL)) date_7_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/16',value,NULL)) date_8_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/16',value,NULL)) date_9_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/16',value,NULL)) date_10_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/16',value,NULL)) date_11_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/16',value,NULL)) date_12_1_16,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/17',value,NULL)) date_1_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/17',value,NULL)) date_2_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/17',value,NULL)) date_3_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/17',value,NULL)) date_4_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/17',value,NULL)) date_5_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/17',value,NULL)) date_6_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/17',value,NULL)) date_7_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/17',value,NULL)) date_8_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/17',value,NULL)) date_9_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/17',value,NULL)) date_10_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/17',value,NULL)) date_11_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/17',value,NULL)) date_12_1_17,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/18',value,NULL)) date_1_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/18',value,NULL)) date_2_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/18',value,NULL)) date_3_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/18',value,NULL)) date_4_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/18',value,NULL)) date_5_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/18',value,NULL)) date_6_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/18',value,NULL)) date_7_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/18',value,NULL)) date_8_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/18',value,NULL)) date_9_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/18',value,NULL)) date_10_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/18',value,NULL)) date_11_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/18',value,NULL)) date_12_1_18,MAX(IF(`date`='1/1/19',value,NULL)) date_1_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='2/1/19',value,NULL)) date_2_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='3/1/19',value,NULL)) date_3_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='4/1/19',value,NULL)) date_4_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='5/1/19',value,NULL)) date_5_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='6/1/19',value,NULL)) date_6_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='7/1/19',value,NULL)) date_7_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='8/1/19',value,NULL)) date_8_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='9/1/19',value,NULL)) date_9_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='10/1/19',value,NULL)) date_10_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='11/1/19',value,NULL)) date_11_1_19,MAX(IF(`date`='12/1/19',value,NULL)) date_12_1_19 FROM flatten GROUP BY key
```

So, now, when you run it  - you will get below result

[image]

Obviously when you run it against your real data - you will get real values instead of NULLs as it is in example above

Finally, you can simply automate above steps using any client of your choice!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have years from 2011 to 2019 for now now and will keep on growing in future. I cant automate with this solution.  It will be helpful if you can also describe the solution mentioned in that link if that is possible. Thanks in Advance!