# Build adjacency matrix from list of weighted edges in BigQuery

Tags: matrix, google-bigquery, transpose

Related issue:
[How to create dummy variable columns for thousands of categories in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu)

I have a table of list of weighted edges which is a list of user-item rating, it looks like this:

```
| userId | itemId | rating
| 001    | 001    | 5.0
| 001    | 002    | 4.0
| 002    | 001    | 4.5
| 002    | 002    | 3.0
```

I want to convert this weighted edge list into a adjacency matrix:

```
| userId | item001 | item002
| 001    | 5.0     | 4.0
| 002    | 4.5     | 3.0
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu), we can do it in two steps, the first step is to extract the matrix entry's value to generate a query, and second step is to run the query which is generated from 1st step.

But my question is how to extract the rating value and use the rating value in the `IF()` statement? My intuition is to put a nested query inside the `IF()` statement such like:

```
IF(itemId = blah, 
                 (select rating 
                  from mytable 
                  where 
                    userId = blahblah 
                    and itemId = blah), 
                 0)
```

But this query looks too expensive, can someone give me an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something  - it is quite similar to the post you referenced

> Step 1 - generate query

```
SELECT 'SELECT userID, ' + 
   GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(
    'SUM(IF(itemId = "' + STRING(itemId) + '", rating, 0)) AS item' + STRING(itemId)
   ) 
   + ' FROM YourTable GROUP BY userId'
FROM (
  SELECT itemId 
  FROM YourTable  
  GROUP BY itemId
)
```

> Step 2 - run generated query

```
SELECT 
  userID, 
  SUM(IF(itemId = "001", rating, 0)) AS item001,
  SUM(IF(itemId = "002", rating, 0)) AS item002 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY userId
```

> Result as expected

```
userID  item001 item002  
001     5.0     4.0  
002     4.5     3.0
```

Comment: ah yes you right, it's similar I thought the rating should be extracted from a sub query..