# Idiomatic equivalent to map structure

Tags: google-bigquery

My analytics involves the need to aggregate rows and to store the number of different values occurrences of a field `someField` in all the rows.

Sample data structure
`[someField, someKey]`

I'm trying to `GROUP BY someKey` and then be able to know for each of the results how many time there was each `someField` values

Example:

```
[someField: a, someKey: 1],
[someField: a, someKey: 1],
[someField: b, someKey: 1],
[someField: c, someKey: 2],
[someField: d, someKey: 2]
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
[someKey: 1, fields: {a: 2, b: 1}],
[someKey: 2, fields: {c: 1, d: 1}],
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
WITH data AS (
  select 'a' someField, 1 someKey UNION all
  select 'a', 1 UNION ALL
  select 'b', 1 UNION ALL
  select 'c', 2 UNION ALL
  select 'd', 2)

SELECT
  someKey,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(someField, freq)) fields
FROM(
  SELECT
    someField,
    someKey,
    COUNT(someField) freq
  FROM data
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Results:

[image]

It won't give exactly the results you are looking for, but it might work to receive the same queries your previous result would. As you said, for each `key` you can retrieve how many times (column `freq`) `someField` happened.

I've been looking for a way on how to aggregate structs and couldn't find one. But retrieving the results as an ARRAY of STRUCTS turned out to be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a smarter way to do this (and get it in the format you want e.g. using an Array for the 2nd column), but this might be enough for you:

```
with sample as (
select 'a' as someField, 1 as someKey UNION all
select 'a' as someField, 1 as someKey UNION ALL
select 'b' as someField, 1 as someKey UNION ALL
select 'c' as someField, 2 as someKey UNION ALL
select 'd' as someField, 2 as someKey)

SELECT
  someKey,
  SUM(IF(someField = 'a', 1, 0)) AS a,
  SUM(IF(someField = 'b', 1, 0)) AS b,
  SUM(IF(someField = 'c', 1, 0)) AS c,
  SUM(IF(someField = 'd', 1, 0)) AS d
FROM
  sample
GROUP BY
  someKey order by somekey asc
```

Results:

```
someKey a   b   c   d
---------------------    
  1     2   1   0   0    
  2     0   0   1   1
```

This is well used technique in BigQuery (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu/34010803#34010803)).

Comment: The a, b, c, and d keys are potentially infinite and unknown at the start, I can juste assume the field name

Comment: It's still possible with unknown keys. You run a query first to generate the SQL. See here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu/34010803#34010803

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to GROUP BY someKey and then be able to know for each of the results how many time there was each someField values

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  someKey,
  someField,
  COUNT(someField) freq
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1, 2
-- ORDER BY someKey, someField
```

> What I would like to achieve:
>      [someKey: 1, fields: {a: 2, b: 1}],
>      [someKey: 2, fields: {c: 1, d: 1}],

This is different from what you expressed in words - it is called pivoting and based on your comment - `The a, b, c, and d keys are potentially infinite` - most likely is not what you need. At the same time - pivoting is easily doable too (if you have some finite number of field values) and you can find plenty of related posts