# SQL - Impala - How to unfold one categorical column into many?

Tags: sql, impala, unfold

I have the following table :

```
user      category    number
1         A           8
1         B           6
2         A           1
2         C           9
3         B           5
```

I want to "unfold" or "dummify" the category column and fill them with the "number" column to obtain:

```
user      cat_A    cat_B    cat_C
1         8        6        0
2         1        0        9
3         0        5        0
```

Is it possible to achieve this in SQL (Impala) ?

I found this question [How to create dummy variable columns for thousands of categories in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu)

However it seems a little bit complex and I'd rather do it in Pandas.

Is there a simpler solution, knowing that I have **10 categories** (A, B, C, D etc)?

Comment: Pivot/conditional aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT user,
        SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'A' THEN number ELSE 0 END) cat_A,  
        SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'B' THEN number ELSE 0 END) cat_B,  
        SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'C' THEN number ELSE 0 END) cat_C     
FROM T 
GROUP BY user
```