# SQLite - Create dummy variable vector/string from multiple columns

Tags: sqlite

I have some data that looks like this:

```
UserID   Category
------   --------
1         a
1         b
2         c
3         b
3         a
3         c
```

A I'd like to binary-encode this grouped by `UserID`: three different values exist in `Category`, so a binary encoding would be something like:

```
UserID    encoding
------    --------
1         "1, 1, 0"
2         "0, 0, 1"
3         "1, 1, 1"
```

i.e., all three values are present for `UserID` = `3`, so the corresponding vector is `"1, 1, 1"`.

Is there a way to do this *without* doing a bunch of `CASE WHEN` statements? There may be dozens of possible values in `Category`

Answer (score 1):

Cross join the distinct users to distinct categories and left join to the table.
Then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function which supports an `ORDER BY` clause, to collect the `0`s and `1`s:

```
WITH 
  users AS (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tablename),
  categories AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Category, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Category) rn
    FROM tablename
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT u.UserID, c.rn,
           '"' || GROUP_CONCAT(t.UserID IS NOT NULL)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY u.UserID ORDER BY c.rn) || '"' encoding
    FROM users u CROSS JOIN categories c
    LEFT JOIN tablename t
    ON t.UserID = u.UserID AND t.Category = c.Category
  )
SELECT DISTINCT userID, 
       FIRST_VALUE(encoding) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY rn DESC) encoding
FROM cte
ORDER BY userID
```

This will work for any number of categories.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f94b3c021bb8c5b05ba9f44f4c70cd19).
Results:

| UserID | encoding |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "1,1,0" |
| 2 | "0,0,1" |
| 3 | "1,1,1" |

Answer (score 0):

First create an encoding table to explicit establish order of categories in the bitmap:

```
create table e (Category int, Encoding int);
insert into e values ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 4);
```

First generate a list of users `u` (cross) joined with the encoding table e to get a fully populated (UserId, Category, Encoding) table.  Then left join the fully populated table with the user supplied data `t`.  The right hand side `t` can now be used to drive if we need to set a bit or not:

```
select
    u.UserId,
    '"' ||
        group_concat(case when t.UserId is null then 0 else 1 end, ', ')
    || '"' 'encoding'
from 
    (select distinct UserID from t) u
    join e
    left natural join t
group by 1
order by e.Encoding
```

and it gives the expected result:

```
1|"1, 1, 0"
2|"0, 0, 1"
3|"1, 1, 1"
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I might have a lot of possible values in the columns: a, b, c, ...zz, so I would need a method to avoid adding them manually.

Comment: How do specify the encoding?

Comment: It's a binary encoding, so if the values A, B, C exist in the data, then the vector "A, B, C" could be mapped to "1, 1, 1" if all values are present for a given UserID, or "0, 0, 0" if none of the values are present, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but is the encoding for zt?  Do you have a table with the encoding and if so what are the values?

Comment: What do you mean by zt? The encoding is technically arbitrary and might change if additional values are added or removed from the dataset. I could also arbitrarily assign an encoding like "B, A, C"

Comment: Basically, I am asking to do this but in SQLite and encoded as a vector instead of columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010002/how-to-create-dummy-variable-columns-for-thousands-of-categories-in-google-bigqu